# JQuery/Javascript: to get checkboxlist enabled or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

There is no problem for to enable or disable this kind of control but what if I only wanna know the status? To know if its status of enable or disable?

```
.prop("disabled",false);
.attr("disabled", true);
```

These are all **SET** not **GET**

or I even tried some like

```
$get("<%=cklst.ClientID %>").disabled;
```

not working.

Any hint? thx!

Comment: Just use `var value=$('#youritem').prop();`

Comment: @SableFoste not working, it throws exception, I am using jquery 1.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

`$("#myid").prop("disabled")`

Jquery docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

As per your example it would probably be:

`$("#<%=cklst.ClientID %>").prop("disabled")`

Note that to set the disabled property, you'd use:

`$("#<%=cklst.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", true)`

---

Ok, so you're using a CheckBoxList, which is slightly different. If you look at the emitted html from this code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ck1" runat="server" Enabled="false"
RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" EnableViewState="true" >
    <asp:ListItem>Item 1 Disabled</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 2 Disabled</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 3 Disabled</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 4 Disabled</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 5 Disabled</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 6 Disabled</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

You'll see it's something like this:

```
<table id="ctl00_cphMain_ck1" disabled="disabled" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphMain$ck1$0" disabled="disabled"><label for="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_0">Item 1 Disabled</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphMain$ck1$1" disabled="disabled"><label for="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_1">Item 2 Disabled</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphMain$ck1$2" disabled="disabled"><label for="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_2">Item 3 Disabled</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphMain$ck1$3" disabled="disabled"><label for="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_3">Item 4 Disabled</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_4" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphMain$ck1$4" disabled="disabled"><label for="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_4">Item 5 Disabled</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphMain$ck1$5" disabled="disabled"><label for="ctl00_cphMain_ck1_5">Item 6 Disabled</label></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

(Now this could vary depending on what type of value you have set for ClientIDMode, and the other parent controls IDs.)

What ASP.NET has done is create a table html element with (effectively) the single ID of your CheckBoxList, and then on each row in the table, you have an html checkbox element with an ID that has been enumerated, eg. ctl00_cphMain_ck1_0, ctl00_cphMain_ck1_1, ctl00_cphMain_ck1_2, etc.

Each of those checkboxes has been set with a disabled property.

So on the client side, when dealing with the checkboxes, you have to target them more specifically. If you just use the CheckBoxList ID, you're going to get an incorrect value, because JQuery won't recognise a disabled property on a table element. So you need to look at one (or more) of the child checkboxes.

So you could do something like this:

```
$("#<%=cklst.ClientID %> input")[0].prop("disabled")
```

That's effectively saying: for the checkbox list TABLE element, get me the first input child element, and tell me what the disabled property is.

Make sense?

Comment: not working, not error but the value is "false" but actually the control is enabled

Comment: Sorry Sean both of them return "false" no matter the control is enabled or disabled.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the disabled property correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/uofuz4L7/

Comment: @Windtalker Why don't you post a sample code which reproduces your issue, as e.g a jsFiddle???

Comment: jsfiddle.net/d2jq6kg5/1 @Sean

Comment: jsfiddle.net/d2jq6kg5/1 @A.Wolff

Comment: Great, very clear, I appreciate you help!  Yes I should have a look at the designer page after it get rendered . Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I don't 'speak' ASP but find this answer very clear, thx for sharing

Comment: Cool. Another option would be to inspect the "disabled" attribute on the table, using the .attr() function in Jquery.